# Route 53 domain not resolving to Network Load Balancer (502 Bad Gateway error)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I am trying to create a record in my public hosted zone in Route 53 to point at my network load balancer. When I create record and go to access the domain I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. But when I try accessing the website using the DNS of the load balancer it loads with no issues.

Any idea why this is happening? My domain's name is make-life-eazy.com

The load balancer's DNS: makelifeeazy-nlb-16a22ca63629cdb5.elb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com

[Route 53 Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEb6Y.png)

Comment: is this a 3rd party domain?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by 3rd part domain? This is the domain assigned by AWS to my load balancer. The issue has been resolved anyways. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to change the name servers in Route 53 to the new name servers of the new hosted zone of the account the domain was transferred to.

Answer (score 0):

When I check how the domain resolves I get:

```
 dig make-life-eazy.com any

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> make-life-eazy.com any
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46425
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 7, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;make-life-eazy.com.            IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
make-life-eazy.com.     60      IN      A       54.252.50.253
make-life-eazy.com.     60      IN      A       13.236.215.67
make-life-eazy.com.     172800  IN      NS      ns-1431.awsdns-50.org.
make-life-eazy.com.     172800  IN      NS      ns-1945.awsdns-51.co.uk.
make-life-eazy.com.     172800  IN      NS      ns-242.awsdns-30.com.
make-life-eazy.com.     172800  IN      NS      ns-825.awsdns-39.net.
make-life-eazy.com.     900     IN      SOA     ns-825.awsdns-39.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

Can you do the same for the load balancer DNS to verify that the A records do match? I am not copying it for you from a screenshot. An image is a really the worst possible format for sharing text information.

Error 502, obviously, is not a DNS error and you DNS for sure resolves to something. It may be enough if there is a http server behind the NLB and it has virtual hosts on, but your one is not set up properly (possibly if you did use some template which sets only the nlb name). Luckily, http servers do have logs. Do you see 502 errors in the http server logs?

Comment: Thank you @petrch for your assistance. I new to AWS and my networking skills are very poor. The output of the dig operation doesn't fit in this reply comment, but I have added the DNS of the ELB to the original post, it is makelifeeazy-nlb-16a22ca63629cdb5.elb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com. The first A record is there, but not the second one (13.236.215.67).

I currently am running a containerized website on Fargate in two VPC subnets which are the target group of the load balancer. With that being said, I have to look into how to get the logs from Fargate.

Comment: you should see (at least some of them) in the fargate console. I think they should be in cloudwatch as well. If you have an ssh key in the container you can ssh in as well (probably from some jump box). BTW, I see the NLB to resolve to 52.64.117.77 which is neither of the IPs. Did you maybe accidentally created the same record in a different region?

Comment: I finally figured out what is happening, I transferred this domain from an another AWS account that I had. What you saw with that dig were IPs from the old records table. I deleted the old host zone, now I am not getting anything when running dig on the domain.

Comment: the domain is registered somewhere. Go to your registrar and change the NS records to the ones in your current route53. That should fix that.

Comment: Yeah I have already done that, now waiting for the request to be processed. Thanks for your help.